# Remove "\" from string

Tags: c#, json, regex, string

I've got string from json.

```
"[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"someOption\":\"2\",\"someText\":\"qweqe\",\"someNumber\":\"123\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"someOption\":\"2\",\"someText\":\"qweqw\",\"someNumber\":\"323\"}]"
```

I want to remove the "\" sign.

Used this for parsing and it didn't work. Debugging shows it's ineffective:

```
Regex.Replace(json, @"\", "");
```

and

```
string signer =  json.Replace(@"\", "");
```

Also Visual Studio shows that pattern @"\"(tried it too in those functions) isn't matching "\" in fact.

I'm confused. Does anyone knows how to create the right pattern here?

I want to retrieve the data later from this match 
ex.

```
[{"id":"1", "someOption":"2", (..) so on}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure whatever you're using to look at the string isn't just showing you an escaped version and in fact it's not escaped? Debuggers and loggers can do that.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have backslashes, or are you viewing the strings in the debugger where it will display double quotes in a string with a delmitting backslash before it?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I'm rather sure - viewed data both before and after trying to remove sign from it and it shows the same

Comment: could it be that you need to escape the '\': `myString.Replace("\\", "")`?

Comment: string signer = json.Replace(@"\"",""). If that gives you error, do json.Replace(@"\","").Replace("\"","");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace \" by ' . i.e.

```
string signer =  json.Replace("\"", "'");
```

So, you have:

```
[{'id':'1', 'someOption':'2', (..) so on}]
```

Now, you can retrieve the data as you want.

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Language is c#, that escape some characters in string. Char " is one.
This means that the string not contains "\", but you see an escaped string.
In debug, you can see not escaped value in watch by clicking magnifying glass.